# Error popup when one upvotes a comment more than once should contain "upvote" instead of "mark"

Tags: bug, error-message, wording, comment-voting

Steps to reproduce:

1. Upvote a comment.
2. Click any link from that page.
3. Press the back button from the browser.
4. The comment will look like it wasn't upvoted. So press the upvote button again.

Result:

> [image]

Bug: "*mark*" in the popup should be "*upvote*" because "*mark*" doesn't make sense here.

Besides, other popups like

> [image]

says "*upvote*", not "*mark*"

Comment: This is a comment that can be used to test the above issue.

Comment: Well, the actual purpose of comment upvote is to *mark* the comment as useful/helpful - think the original tooltip long ago also said something like that.

Comment: off topic but curious, why jpg screenshot? For those .png is usually better, preserving the full quality.

Comment: @ShadowWizard , I see. Ok. I'll use .png now onwards. I don't have much knowledge about images and qualities...

Comment: Well, jpg are useful for "full scale" pictures, .png is better for screenshots showing text - the few extra bytes are worth it. :)

Comment: When you do the same steps except with flagging a comment it gives correct error in saying "you've already flagged this comment". +1 to switch to upvote

Comment: I marked this bug report.